# Java compiler prohibit the creation in the inner class method with same name as in the outer class if the signatures are different

Tags: java, inheritance, javac, inner-classes

Why this code work:

```
class Parent {
    private void methodA(String a){
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    class Inner {

        void test(int a){
            methodA("1");
        }
    }
}
```

But This code not work(I just add method to inner class with same name and another signature):

```
class Parent {
    private void methodA(String a){
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    class Inner {

        private void methodA(int a){
            System.out.println(a);
        }

        void test(int a){
            methodA("1");
        }
    }
}
```

**I do not ask how to make it work. I want to mean why the second option doesn't work? I want an explanation, not a solution.**

Comment: I expect that I can call `methodA("1");` from outer class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because you changed the meaning of the name `methodA`.

Because a method called `methodA` is present in the body of the class in which you are invoking a method called `methodA`, the compiler doesn't look at the surrounding scopes.

The specific bit of the language spec is [Sec 15.12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1) (emphasis mine):

> If the form is MethodName, that is, just an Identifier, then:
>
> ...
>
> If there is an enclosing type declaration of which that method is a member, **let T be the innermost such type declaration**. The class or interface to search is T.

You can invoke the parent method still via:

```
Parent.this.methodA("1");
```

Comment: then why does the same code work in `eclips` compiler and not work in `javac`?

Comment: And why it work if I change methodA from private to protected in Outer class

Comment: "And why it work if I change private to protected in Outer class" it doesn't for me. "why does the same code work in eclips compiler" sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

When compiler starts scanning the code it first look for the nearest scope availability. If it doesn't find it then only it go for a higher scope.

In your case, compiler will find method `methodA` in `Inner` class. So it will not look for the method available in `Parent` class.

Still if you want to force compiler to look for `Parent` class method than you have to use below code.

```
Parent.this.methodA("1");
```